# Test insert query using mysqlslap

Tags: mysql, query-performance

First, I am new to mysqlslap
I want to test insert query using mysqlslap on my existing database. Table which I want to test has primary and composite unique.

So, how to do performance test on this table using mysqlslap concurrently?

I should not face mysql error duplicate key

Below is skeleton for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  column1 bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  column2 varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  datacolumn1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  datacolumn2 VARCHAR(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY profiles_UNIQUE (column1,column2),
  INDEX id_idx (id),
  INDEX unq_id_idx (column1, column2) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=innodb DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Please help me on this

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE`.  A `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX`.  So, your two `INDEXes` are redundant and should be dropped.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. Will this redundant affect performance?

Comment: Yes, it affects `INSERTs`, `DELETEs` and some `UPDATEs`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with benchmarking `INSERTs`.  The speed will change as you insert more and more, but not in an easily predictable way.

An Insert performs (roughly) this way:

1. Check for duplicate key.  You have two unique keys (the PK and a UNIQUE).  Each BTree will be drilled down to check for a dup.  Assuming no dup...
2. The row will be inserted in the data (a BTree keyed by the PK)
3. A "row" will be inserted into each Unique's BTree.  In your case, there is a BTree effectively ordered by (column1, column2) and containing (id).
4. Stuff is put into the "Change Buffer" for each non-unique index.

If you had an `AUTO_INCREMENT` or a `UUID` or ..., there will be more discussion.

The Change Buffer is effectively a "delayed write" to non-unique indexes.  This delay has to be dealt with eventually.  That is, at some time, things will slow down if a background process fails to keep up with the changes.  That is, if you insert 1 million rows, you may not hit this slowdown; if you insert 10 million rows, you may hit it.

Another variable:  `VARCHAR(2048)` (and other `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns) *may* or *may not* be stored "off record".  This depends on the size of the row, the size of that column, and "row format".  A big string *may* take an extra disk hit, thereby slowing down the benchmark, probably by a noticeable amount.  That is, if you benchmark with only small strings and certain row formats, you will get a faster insert time than otherwise.

And you need to understand how the benchmark program runs -- versus how your application will run:

- Insert rows one at a time in a single thread -- each being a transaction.
- Insert rows one at a time in a single thread -- lots batched into a transaction.
- Insert 100 rows at a time in a single thread in a single transaction.
- LOAD DATA.
- Multiple threads with each of the above.
- Different transaction isolation settings.
- Etc.

(I am not a fan of benchmarks because of how many flaws they have.)  The 'best' benchmark for comparing hardware or limited schema/app changes:  Capture the "general log" from a running application; capture the database at the start of that; time the re-applying of that log.

**Designing a table/insert for 50K inserted rows/sec**

- Minimize indexes.  In your case, all you need is `PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2)`; toss the rest; toss `id`.  Please explain what col1 and col2 are; there may be more tips here.
- Get rid of the table.  Seriously, consider summarize the 50K rows every second and store only the summarization.  If it is practical, this will greatly speed things up.  Or maybe a minute's worth.
- Batch insert rows in some way.  The details here depend on whether you have one or many clients doing the inserts, whether you need to massage the data as it comes, in, etc.  More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table
- What is in those strings?  Can/should they be 'normalized'?
- Let's discuss the math.  Will you be loading about 10 *petabytes* per year?  Do you have that much disk space?  What will you do with the data?  How long will it take to read even a small part of that data?  Or will it be a "write only" database??
- More math.  50K rows * 0.5KB = 25MB writing to disk per second.  What device do you have? Can it handle, say, 2x that?  (With your original schema, it would be more like 60MB/s because of all the indexes.)

**After comments**

OK, so more like 3TB before you toss the data and start over (in 2 hours)?  For that, I would suggest `PARTITION BY RANGE` and use some time function that gives you 5 minutes in each partition.  This will give you a reasonable number of partitions (about 25) and the `DROP PARTITION` will be dropping only about 100GB, which might not overwhelm the filesystem.  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

As for the strings... You suggest 25KB, yet the declarations don't allow for that much???

Comment: My application has more inserts for example 50,000 inserts per second on above table. In order to improve the performance, what is the best way to design the table?

Comment: Thanks Rick. You nailed it and showed me many aspects to tune. I will check every factor and try to do optimization. I have answers for below 2 questions in hand:

Comment: What is in those strings? Can/should they be 'normalized'?
---> Both Strings may occupy 25KB size. I accept, it should be normalized.

Comment: Let's discuss the math. Will you be loading about 10 petabytes per year? Do you have that much disk space? What will you do with the data? How long will it take to read even a small part of that data? Or will it be a "write only" database??
---> We will maintain only 2 hours data in this table. Scheduler will delete the data every 2 hours. Our app don't have much read operation compared to writes. External system will read the data randomly say every 5 minutes or 6 minutes.